# Application deployment on Payara with JMS connection problems

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, payara

We have noticed our web application is not being deployed on Payara 4.1 when Message Driven Beans fail to connect to the server properly or the queues are missing. We'd rather have the application up and running, then fail a deployment due to JMS connection issues. Is there a way on Payara to prevent deployment crashes due to JMS failing?

EDIT: We use IBM MQ with the wmq.jmsra resource adapter.

Comment: Is this IBM MQ?

Comment: Yes, we use IBM MQ.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state which exact version of Payara (e.g. 4.1.174) and I forgot when this was added, but could you please try to set the system property

```
-Ddeployment.resource.validation=false
```

and check if this behaves as you desire.

You can do

```
asadmin create-jvm-options -Ddeployment.resource.validation=false
```

or simply put it in your domain.xml.

Comment: I have tried but it did not work. I still get an error like: `Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue '(cut)'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.`

Comment: Which exact version of Payara are you using?

Comment: We are using 4.1.2.174.

Comment: That's the version when "-Ddeployment.resource.validation=false" was added. But it looks like it does not work on resource adapters. :-/